# How to implement DIP in an MVC environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, density-independent-pixel

Dependency Inversion Principle states that higher level modules should not depend on lower level modules. Both should depend on abstractions. I do understand that principle. But as I'm using ASP.NET MVC, I often get my controller methods as:

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(string userValue)
    {
        User user = MyDatabase.GetUser();
        if (!user.CheckSomeCondition(userValue))
        { //Something failed. Try again.
            return View();
        }
        user.Update(userValue);         
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
```

I believe this violates DIP because the result of my controller depends on the User class. In this scenario, I cannot think of a way of decoupling the Controller from my User class. Is there a way to get rid of this dependency? Or is this just fine to do it this way in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

create an interface and inject an implementation on that to your mvc controller.

```
public interface IMyDataAccess
{
  User GetUser();
}
```

Create your implementation now.

```
public class MyMongoDBDataAccess : IMyDataAccess
{
  public User GetUser()
  {
    //return a user from my fancy db
  }
}
```

Now in your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   IMyDataAccess dao;
   public HomeController(IMyDataAccess myDataAccess)
   {
     this.dao=myDataAccess;
   }
   public ActionResult MyAction(string userValue)
   {
      User user=this.dao.GetUser();
      //return something to the view as needed.
   }
}
```

You may use any dependency injection framework like [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) to inject the desired implementation of your interface to your controller.

If you want bring in more layers like Business Layer, Service layer, follow the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks very good. Now, what would you return in MyAction ?  If  I want to update the user based on userValue I need to know if I'm returning an error or a redirect. Can MyAction depend on the user in this case?

Comment: @JorgeZuverza Sure you can. In case of error, Return the data you want to show ( possibly a viewmodel  (it could be just a string also) to the view.

Answer (score 2):

If your application structure is like below, than you are implementing DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle).

DIP says that a layer in your application should depend on a interface, not by an implementation. Like below, `Service` is depending on `IDatabase` not `MyDatabase`

```
public interface IDatabase { 
    Update(User user); 
}
public interface MyDatabase : IDatabase 
{ 
    public Update(User user) {
        // update user
    }
}

public interface IService { 
    Update(string user); 
}
public class Service : IService 
{
    private IDatabase _database;
    public Service(IDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }


    public Update(User user) {
        _database.Update(user);
    }
}
```

DIP also says that high level modules like `MvcController` don't need to know/depend on low level modules, `MyDatabase`.

```
public class MvcController : Controller
{
    private IService _service;
    private IUserValidator _userValidator;
    public MvcController(IService service, IUserValidator userValidator) // depending on abstraction
    {
        _service = service;
        _userValidator = userValidator;
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction(string userValue)
    {
        if (!_userValidator.CheckSomeCondition(userValue))
        {   //Something failed. Try again.
            return View();
        }
        User user = _service.GetUser();
        user.UserValue = userValue;
        _service.Update(user);         
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. I recommend to take a look on **3-tier-architecture** doing this you will improve your understanding of **SOLID** and your application will be more organized.
2. If in your case `MyDatabase` is a module Higher then `User` than, you are not respecting DIP principles, because your Controller make uses of a lower module.

Answer (score 1):

DIP or IoC says High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.

It means that High Level class should not depend on concrete class but it should depend on Interface.

But here you are talking about **User** class which seems a **DTO (Data Transfer Object)**.

So In that case, You must have to use that DTO in your last layer to either return data or deal with data.

But you should not be using POCO classes provided by entity framework, Instead you should create and use your DTO classes as ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

Ups, this is how I do it when using ASP.NET Web API, not sure if this works MVC Controller. But there is Unity.MVC (v3 or v4 or v5) lib ([Unity.Mvc4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/)) that you can use!
And you can wire it up like this, you should call this code in the Application_Start event!

```
public static class WebApiBootstrapper
    {
        public static void Init(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.DependencyResolver = new WebApiDependencyResolver(container); // DI container for use in WebApi
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                WebApiRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            });

            // Web API mappings
            // All components that implement IDisposable should be 
            // registered with the HierarchicalLifetimeManager to ensure that they are properly disposed at the end of the request.
            container.RegisterType<IYourController, YourController>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyDataBase)));
        }
    }
```

But before running tthis code you have to register the type mapping

```
container.RegisterType<IMyDatabse, MyDataBase>();
```

And you also have to implement the DependencyResolver class:

```
public class WebApiDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IUnityContainer container;

        public WebApiDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new WebApiDependencyResolver(child);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

In your controller:

```
public class YourController : ApiController, IYourController
{

    IDataBase _db;
    public PlayGroundController(IDataBase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```